# Placeholder text not disappearing on click at anywhere in input box in IE7 & iE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css

I have a Fancy input box

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" class="search" name="q"/>

.search {
    font-family: arial;
    height: 32px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('/image/myimage.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

It is working fine in all other browsers except IE8 or less so i had to do this to stretch the image.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>              
    <style type="text/css">
        #search{
                 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image/myimage.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Now i wanted a placeholder text in the search box so i used [Placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/) file because placeholder is not supported in IE 7 and 8.

Now the issue is that when i click on the input box in IE 8 or 7 then the input box is not getting selected. Due to which the placeholder text is not disappearing.
I believe the alphaimageloader is the issue because when i remove it then the placeholder works fine.
Can anyone advice me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DZFs9/)

```
var placeHolderSupport = document.createElement('input').placeholder != undefined;

$(function() {
  if (!placeHolderSupport) {
    $search=$("#search");
    var ph = $("#search").attr("placeholder");
    if ($search.val()==="") {
      $search.val(ph);
      $search.prop("defaultValue",ph);
    }
    $search.on("focus",function() {
      if (this.value===this.defaultValue) this.value=""; 
    })
    .on("blur",function() {
      if (this.value==="") this.value=this.defaultValue; 
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool your code is working. But again as i explained about the image which i have scaled on top of the input box. it is messing with input box. So it is not working in IE7 and 8

Comment: I tested in IE8, I am not sure what the CSS did, but no effect inside the fiddle

Comment: Ok wait. I will try to create a fiddle for you.

Comment: I have your transforms in my fiddle too - and you can delete the "It is not working" now :)

Comment: You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DZFs9/embedded/result/ that the image is not scaling properly. Since it is not scaling thats why it is working.